# Is it possible for an end portal to not generate in the legacy console (xbox 360) edition of minecraft

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I recently loaded up a new world in the xbox 360 edition of minecraft in survival, and then once again in creative to find the stronghold. I couldnt find the end portal in creative, but since that happens almost every time I go in creative and look for a portal, i thought, "ok, i'll just go to the stronghold in  my survival world", but i couldnt find the end portal either. I was hoping someone knows whats going on, whether it got overwritten, or if i just have bad luck with seeds.
Here is the seed if that helps: -7368897920777790432.
Oh, and here are the coords: X: 146, Y: 45, Z: 132.

Comment: im pretty sure 3 used to spawn in every world